# jQuery Range Slider - saving date range

Tags: html, mysql, jquery-plugins, slider, date-range

Hope this is not a duplicate because i didn't find question like this.

I'm using **jQRangeSlider** for date range. The slider works showing min and max date and changing as i move it. I want to pull the date and save it into **MySQL** database. I need the dates like this:

```
<input type="text" name="min" />
<input type="text" name="max" />
```

So far i didn't have any luck in making it work.

I have this:

```
<script>

$("#slider").dateRangeSlider();

 </script>
```

and this:

```
// Date slider
var dateValues = $("#dateSlider").dateRangeSlider("values");
console.log(dateValues.min.toString() + " " + dateValues.max.toString());
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an event handler that triggers when the slider changes

```
$("#slider").on("valuesChanging", function(e, data){
  console.log("from: " + data.values.min + ", to: " + data.values.max);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vM844/1019/)

Comment: I'd suggest using valuesChanged instead of valuesChanging because it's triggered only once the change is done.